# Convert runif to h:m:s

Tags: r, datetime, type-conversion

I have a problem with converting numeric to time in hour:minute:second. I would like to choose 10000 random numbers from uniform distribution and convert them to format h:m:s

```
X <- runif(10000, 0, 86400)
```

After this, I have 10000 numbers of seconds within one day. I would like to convert it to format hour:minute:second. For example:

```
44 ---> 00:00:44
```

Comment: From linked post: `td <- seconds_to_period(44); sprintf('%02d:%02d:%02d', td@hour, minute(td), second(td))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `times` in the chron package:

```
library(chron)
times(runif(10))
##  [1] 14:21:18 09:56:58 15:28:11 07:13:17 17:48:09 10:25:43 23:09:23 09:10:28
##  [9] 12:29:03 12:12:11
```